# Jquery...hide dropdown if click elsewhere except a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown, which will be closed by calling blur(). It should be closed if you click somewhere else than the dropdown.

Now i want to add a function, so if you click somewhere else, the dropdown is still going to be closed UNLESS you click the div called `<div class="changeask"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate("*", "mousedown touchend", function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).closest("div.select2-container").get(0), attr;
        if (target) {
            $(document).find("div.select2-container-active").each(function () {
                if (this !== target ) $(this).data("select2").blur();
            });
        } else {
            target = $(e.target).closest("div.select2-drop").get(0);
            var changeask = $("div.changeask");
            $(document).find("div.select2-drop-active").each(function () {
                if (this !== target && this !== changeask) $(this).data("select2").blur();
            });
        }
```

Here is the code I have now... I tried lots of ways but it still close once i click somewhere else than the dropdown.

Any ideas?

I tried to revise the code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate("*", "mousedown touchend", function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).closest("div.select2-container").get(0), attr;
        var changeask = $(e.target).closest('.changeask').length != 0;

        if (target) {
            $(document).find("div.select2-container-active").each(function () {
                if (this !== target && this!== changeask ) $(this).data("select2").blur();
            });
        } else {
            target = $(e.target).closest("div.select2-drop").get(0);
            $(document).find("div.select2-drop-active").each(function () {
                if (this !== target && this!== changeask) $(this).data("select2").blur();
            });
        }
```

But still not works... Thanks for the help..I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

how about checking if the click happened inside the **changeask** div

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   if($(e.target).closest('.changeask').length != 0) return false;
   $('.changeask').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... I need to hide both changeask and the dropdown if you click somewhere else, and keep showing them at the same time if you click inside one of them....

Comment: I just added some updated codes in my question. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try only triggering the event if the click happens in an element that is not the dropdown or the changeask div:

```
$(document).on("mousedown touchend","*:not(.changeask, .yourselect)",function(e){
...
})
```

Comment: `$(document).on("mousedown touchend","*:not(.changeask, .select2-results)",function(e){
$(this).data("select2").blur();
});` I tried to change to this...but in this case even i click somewhere else the dropdown is not going to be hidden.